# How to convert Jmeter Reponse data in to Byte? How to store the Byte value into CSV file?

Tags: java, jmeter, javabeans, performance-testing, beanshell

Our new requirements is there is script A we need to run on two different environment 1 and environment 2.

So we need to convert the response data into on Byte and store into Csv file. Later we need to compare the both byte result from different environment.

**But now we need to know how to convert the Response data into Byte and store in byte value in one file?**

Any can please help us

Comment: Alright, what do you think about posting some code that you guys have made? Then, we can start discussing...

Comment: Actually we don't have any code now, we need to write but before that we need some idea about this and how to convert into byte ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing response data is not something recommended as it causes high Disk IO overhead. I would suggest modifying your design a little bit, i.e.

1. Switch to "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler and tick the box `Save repsonse as MD5 hash`

   [image: JMeter Save Response as MD5 hash]
2. When you run your test you will see [MD5 checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) like `09b9c392dc1f6e914cea287cb6be34b0`. The idea is that equal responses will have equal MD5 hashes and storing hashes is a more lightweight process.

Be aware that you can also use [MD5Hex Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion) in order to automatically fail sampler if response isn't equal to expected, check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for details.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Wea are implemented the MD5HEX and we are getting the hash values like ***09b9c392dc1f6e914cea287cb6be34b0***, But Every time we are getting different value, so While using MD5Hex Assertion  we are getting fail response due to every time value is changing.

Comment: It is possible to store the response data into File? using Bean shell post processor?

Comment: It is, the relevant code is as simple as `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("response.txt"), data);`. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for detailed explanations and examples

Comment: import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

// Get the variable(s) from the JMeter script
tempVar = vars.get("FiltersByPersonPeoplegeopage")


// Open File(s)
f = new FileOutputStream(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()+"\\sampletest.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 

// Write data to file 
p.println( tempVar );

// Close File(s)
p.close();f.close(); 


we  are implemented above it is able to store the data but every time first value is storing ***null***, Why it is storing null values i need to remove, can we know how to remove the null value

Comment: Variable `${FiltersByPersonPeoplegeopage}` doesn't have any value. Wrap your code with `if (vars.get("FiltersByPersonPeoplegeopage") != null) { //your code here}`. If  you need to save a JMeter Variable value  I'd recommend using  [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property. Add `sample_variables=FiltersByPersonPeoplegeopage` line to *user.properties* file and JMeter it will store its value in results file. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for details

Comment: we are doing the correlation and capture the response data and it store int o ${FiltersByPersonPeoplegeopage} debug sampler.  but if we are run for 60 sec  means first value it stored null and remaining actual response data is store into csv file

Comment: We need t convert the json into java object. How to do it in jmeter, we can use Beanshell Postprocessor.We need to just read it into object with parser